# How to access view tag in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm using ImageView's tag to store a map of values like this

```
imageView.setTag(R.id.TAG_ID, id)
imageView.setTag(R.id.TAG_PATH, path)
```

At some point I clear the tag

```
imageView.tag = null
```

What is the right way to access the tag in Kotlin considering it can be null?

Currently I'm doint it like this

```
imageView.tag?.let { //it: Any
    id = imageView.getTag(ID).toString()
    path = imageView.getTag(PATH).toString()
}
```

It it possible to get the values using `it`?

**Update**

I have just found out that `tag` is always `null` even after calling `setTag(R.id, value)`, and hense setting `tag = null` and `imageView.tag?.let` make no sense.

So supplementary question is how to reset the entire tag map and check if there is any tag key defined.

Comment: Don't make it null. Clear it. Or replace it by a new empty map. Why is `it`of type Any. What's the source code of imageView?

Comment: imageViewis is `ImageView`. `it` is of type `any` because it refers to `tag`, not the view. How do you clear the tag? I can't find `clear` method on `tag`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val id = imageView.getTag(ID) as String? 
val path = imageView.getTag(PATH) as String?
```

Comment: And the explanation for the OP: `view.tag` returns the tag object that was set with `view.tag =`, which you didn't use. You need to use the `getTag()` method that take a key parameter, since you set your tags using keys. Using `as String?` properly give you a nullable reference (provided the set object was a String or null). `toString()` converts whatever it is, even null, into a non-nullable String. `null` would be turned into a String with value `"null"`.